# Arch Linux USB installation media reboots to Windows after few minutes

Tags: linux, boot, usb, arch-linux

I made an Arch Linux bootable USB drive using Ventoy. After booting into the USB drive, everything was fine until it gets stuck on "Wait until kernel time synchronized" session. Then it takes a restart to Windows.

I have also tried to install Garuda Linux, same problem here. I checked the USB drive using CHKDSK and Drive Check option on Windows, but everything was fine there.

I did install Ubuntu before but with another USB. Wonder if the USB is faulty.

Comment: Could be USB, but I'd suggest removing all partitions from the USB drive, and using Rufus or an alternative to make the installation media. See https://alternativeto.net/software/rufus/